# Plotting imshow inside subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to plot tests from an `imshow` function inside an `subplot`. This works fine when I only include one object to be plotted, but when I use 4 objects, still only one is shown. The function I am using to create the objects are from [here.](https://github.com/jeslago/epftoolbox/blob/master/epftoolbox/evaluation/_dm.py#L16)

Apart from not all objects being shown I also get the following error:

`ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None`

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8,8))
ax1.set_title('Zone 1')
ax1.plot(plot_multivariate_DM_test(df['Price_REG1'].iloc[17544:],
                          predictions_22_1, norm=1, title='DM test', savefig=False, path=''))
ax2.set_title('Zone 2')
ax2.plot(plot_multivariate_DM_test(df['Price_REG2'].iloc[17544:],
                          predictions_22_2, norm=1, title='DM test', savefig=False, path=''))
ax3.set_title('Zone 3')
ax3.plot(plot_multivariate_DM_test(df['Price_REG3'].iloc[17544:],
                          predictions_22_3, norm=1, title='DM test', savefig=False, path=''))
ax4.set_title('Zone 4')
ax4.plot(plot_multivariate_DM_test(df['Price_REG4'].iloc[17544:],
                          predictions_22_4, norm=1, title='DM test', savefig=False, path=''))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can't call `ax1.plot(...)` with as argument the result of another plot function. Many custom plotting function support an `ax=` keyword. If not, you can call `plt.sca(ax1)` ("set current ax") just before your call to `plot_multivariate_DM_test(df['Price_REG1'], ...)`. And similarly for the other 3 subplots.

Comment: How could I see if the plotting function supports the `ax=` keyword?

Comment: You can try `plot_multivariate_DM_test(df['Price_REG1'], .ax=ax1, ...)` and check whether that plots on the first subplot.  Depending on how it is implemented, it might or might not throw an error (or a warning).  Did you try calling `plt.sca(ax1)`?

Comment: I tried the `plt.sca(ax1)` on all axes, and it worked like a charm. Thanks!